# How to clear all app data from root directory for logout purpose?

Tags: android

Whenever user is logged in their account, some database and shared preference store some data according to logged user, But after the logout and re-login previous data is still appear.

So, I want to delete this for preventing user privacy.

```
Logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mAuth.signOut();
                //deletappData();
                Intent loginIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
            }
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // To Clear Your Shared Preferences : 

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                 editor.clear();
                 editor.commit();

// Clear SQLite Database : 

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    protected static final String           LOG_TAG = "MyApplication";

    private static DatabaseAdapter          mDb;

    private static MyApplication    mInstance;

    /**
     * @return The instance of the database adapter.
     */
    public static DatabaseAdapter getDatabaseAdapter() {
        return mDb;
    }

    /**
     * @return The instance of the application.
     */
    public static Context getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Application::onCreate");
        mInstance = this;
        mDb = new DatabaseAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        // Close the internal db
        getDatabaseAdapter().close(DatabaseAdapter.INTERNAL);

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "::onTerminate::");
        super.onTerminate();
    }
}
```